# React fixed size text block

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React, and I want to create a text block in fixed-size with border and to be able to present a list or text inside it.

I've tried to use a border on `<div>` and put a list inside it, but when the list was too long it escaped out of the border, instead of having a scroll bar.

```
        <div style={{border: '2px solid black', height: 100}}>
            <ol>
                {this.props.commands.map((command) => <li>{command}</li>)}
            </ol>
        </div>
```

Is there a way to show a list inside the fixed-size box with border, and with a scroll bar when the list is too long?
Thanks for helping

Comment: Do you have a picture please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add an overflow property (scroll or auto) to the inline css like this:

```
<div style={{border: '2px solid black', height: 100, overflow: 'scroll'}}>
    <ol>
         {this.props.commands.map((command) => <li>{command}</li>)}
    </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

welcome to react!

Yes, this is most definitely possible. Try adding the style of your `div`:

```
overflow: 'auto',
```

You can read more [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow/).